# RAM compatibility for the HP Proliant DL320e Gen8 v2

Tags: memory, hp-proliant, memory-usage, hpe

I've got a handful of servers to assemble. I've got a few HP Proliant DL320e Gen8 V2 servers with the 2 LFF hard drive slots and 4 RAM slots.

It came with a stick of PC3 12800E 11-13-E3 RAM, and I'm not sure what those last couple of things are supposed to designate, if anything.

I checked the PDF and it doesn't seem to detail whether or not I need to use HPE SmartMemory or I can use any old UDIMM sticks, just that it supports up to 32GB for 8GBx4 config.

Can I use *any* kind of RAM? The only hard requirement is that it seems to need ECC. Can it be any brand? I'm not sure, and I can't seem to find a solid answer in the product's online-available documentation in its [PDF](https://www.hpe.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04128107.pdf) or [online memory configurator](https://h22195.www2.hpe.com/DDR4memoryconfig/Home/Legal). Near the end of the PDF it shows some HPE-provided RAM options that are all ECC. The wording for rules and guidelines obfuscates this more without detailing if using their specific memory is a guideline or a rule.

**I need to know if using HP/HPE SmartMemory is an actual hard requirement, or just a best practice**. I appreciate your advice, but I'm looking for an answer, not an opinion.

> Standard Memory Plus Optional Memory Up to 32 GB memory is available with the optional installation of 4 x 8GB PC3-12800E UDIMM ECC DDR3 UDIMM Memory kits, operating at 1600MHz when fully populated at 2 DIMMs per Channel in 4 slots. NOTE: The below chart does not represent all possible memory configurations. NOTE: For best performance, it is recommended that customer installs memory in identical pairs
>
> General Memory Population *Rules* and ***Guidelines***:
>
> • The HPE ProLiant DL320e Gen8v2Server has four memory slots
>
> • There are two channels per server with two DIMM slot per channel
>
> • Memory channel A consists of the two (2) DIMMs that are closest to the 
>   processor 
>   • Memory channel B consists of the two (2) DIMMs that are furthest from the 
>   processor
>
> • Different types of processors have different types of memory support.
>
> • Support for single/dual-rank 1333/1600 MT/s ECC UDIMM (unbuffered DIMMS)
>
> • The server supports up to 32 GB (4 x 8-GB) for Unbuffered DIMMs
>
> • No support for RDIMMs; Non-ECC UDIMMs
>
> • Do not install DIMMs if the processor is not installed
>
> • Populate DIMMs from heaviest load (double-rank) to lightest load (single-rank)
>
> • *Always use HPE qualified DIMM*

Answer (score 3):

I ended up finding the answer to this one is a ***no, you don't need to use HP/HPE SmartMemory*** in the Proliant DL320e Gen8 v2 after getting someone in the server room to hook me up with the part number on the pre-installed RAM sticks. HP didn't even provide us their own HP SmartMemory... They gave us a *4GB* stick of this, which isn't even supposed to be something they sell, with 8GB  being the supposed minimum config:

> Micron 4GB PC3-12800 DDR3-1600MHz ECC Unbuffered CL11 240-Pin DIMM
>   Dual Rank Memory Module Mfr P/N **MT18JSF51272AZ**-**1G6K1ZE**

Unless they just forgot to slap their HP/HPE SmartMemory sticker over Micron's label ;) haha. You tell me ***shrug*** Oh and that missing 4 gigs of RAM too... I still don't feel too confident with this answer, but it's better than nothing. I'm kind of suspicious that someone took some liberties with idle hardware, but only because I can't prove that the stick the guy sent me was what HP actually shipped them off with.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use *just any old RAM*. Do the right thing and use the HP-specific parts or equivalent.

This has warranty, support and monitoring implications. Look for these parts...

---

[image]

Comment: I understand that it's preferred, but I'm on a tight budget. If I don't _have_ to use it, I would like to know my options. Do you know if I have to use it?

Comment: You're approaching this the wrong way. This RAM is not expensive, and it's generally a good idea to use HP parts in ProLiant servers.